# How to manage GEE assets with service account (Permission issue)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I need to export some images to my GEE Assets using the Python API and I am getting this error: "Insufficient permissions to create asset 'users/ramizsami95/kyrgyz/ndvi_anomaly".
This is my code:

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(
        image=anomaly,
        description='NDVI-anomaly',
        assetId='users/ramizsami95/kyrgyz/ndvi_anomaly')
task.start()
```

In the Python code, I have authenticated with a service account that is created from my Gmail account and it seems like it can't access my GEE assets. Now I have two questions:
1) Is there a way that I can give owner access to this kyrgyz folder to my service account? (I have given writer permission already)
2) Do we have separate assets for the service account that I am missing?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.